# Sql Server Replication or SyncFramework

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, replication

I have three database servers, all of them runing SQL Server 2008.

Two of them are located in two diferent stores (LocalServers), the other one is on a remote hosting environment (RemoteServer).

The (RemoteServer) contains the most uptodate information about products, prices, etc.. LocalServers contains a copy of the tables and the Orders generated at each store. I need to publish (LocalServers) orders to the (RemoteServer) and download products, customers and prices from (RemoteServer) at least once a day.At the end of the day (RemoteServer) must contain the information from sales at each store but (LocalServers) does no require to have other stores sales.

LocalServers are able to communicate with RemoteServer, this is one-way traffic. Communication from RemoteServer to the LocalServers isn't available.

What kind of replication fits my problem? Sync Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server merge replication with pull subscriptions seems like it would be appropriate in this case.

Merge replication can merge the results of the two local servers into the remote server.  The publisher would be the remote server, and the subscribers would be the local servers.

"Pull" does not indicate the direction of the data flow, which is two-way.  In a "pull" subscription, the merge is initiated from the subscriber, not the publisher, which is consistent with the communication requirement.

A row filter can be used to partition the orders table so each local server only sees its own order data.  The product/pricing would not be filtered, and would be common to all members.